# Find out if a sting in Notepad++ contains a certain number using regex

Tags: regex

I have several lines in Notepad++ that contains:

```
Modules = "3,40,40,40" Modules = "3,40,40,40,40,40,40" Modules = "3,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15".
```

I want to use regex to only highlight or count the ones that contains the number 40. How? This is what i got so far:

```
(Modules\s=\s.+)
```

Comment: Try `Modules\s=\s"[^"]*\b40\b[^"]*"` - it should work if there are no float/double values in between quotes.

Comment: Note that if your `Modules="..."` appear each on different line, `Modules = ".*?\b40\b.*?"` and `Modules\s=\s"[^"]*\b40\b[^"]*"` will work fine. If these substrings appear on the same line (2 or more), then just note,  in case there is a non-match and then a match, the `.*?\b40\b` will find the same number of matches, but the [matches will be different](https://regex101.com/r/UmsLeP/1). It does not look like a problem in this scenario though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no float/double values in between quotes, use

```
Modules\s=\s"[^"]*\b40\b[^"]*"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N3W7SB/1/)

**Details**

- `Modules` - a substring
- `\s=\s` - a `=` enclosed with 1 whitespace
- `"` - a double quote
- `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than `"`
- `\b40\b` - `40` as a whole word
- `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than `"`
- `"`  - a double quote

If you need to match `40` only in between commas and start/end of string, use

```
Modules\s=\s"(?:[^"]*,)?40(?:,[^"]*)?"
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/N3W7SB/2). The difference here is the `(?:[^"]*,)?40(?:,[^"]*)?`: `(?:[^"]*,)?` matches an optional sequence of any 0+ chars other than `"` followed with `,` and `(?:,[^"]*)?` matches an optional sequence of `,` followed with any 0+ chars other than `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is actually a bit tricky, because you want to match the number 40 in any position in the CSV list of numbers.  That is, all of the following three lines should match:

```
Modules = "40,50,4"
Modules = "30,40"
Modules = "10,40,50"
```

To handle this, and assuming the CSV lists have no whitespace or decimals, we use `\b40\b` as the pattern.  Consider this pattern:

```
Modules = ".*?\b40\b.*?"
```

## Demo

Comment: My understanding is that each line can have more than one `Modules = "..."` entry, in which case you'd need to exclude `"` from the `.*?`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol It depends on what the OP wants.  I thought it just wanted to highlight lines which have a match.  In that case, it doesn't matter which match we find.